# Average and Percent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average

In an Math Exam there are 80 more men than women. The result showed that the women's average is 20% higher than men's, and that the total average is 75%. what is the women's average?
So far I did ... 
$$H=W+80$$ $$\overline{W}=1,2\overline{H}\Rightarrow \overline{H}=\frac{\overline{W}}{1,2}$$
but $$\overline{H}=\frac{S_H}{H}\Rightarrow S_H=H\overline{H}$$ and $$\overline{W}=\frac{S_W}{W}\Rightarrow S_W=W\overline{W}$$

as $$75\%=\frac{S_W+S_H}{H+W}\Rightarrow 75\%=\frac{W\overline{W}+(W+80)\frac{\overline{W}}{1,2}}{2W+80}$$
I've tried but I couldn't handle the math till the end.

Comment: You should define your terms.  It appears $W$ is the number of women, $H$ is the number of men, $S_H$ is the sum of the men's percentages and $S_W$ is the sum of the women's percentages.  People shouldn't have to figure that out from your computation.  Good for you for showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have enough information to answer the question.  If there are millions of people taking the exam, the excess of $80$ won't matter and the women score $85\%$ and the men score $65\%$.  If there was $1$ woman and $81$ men the woman scored $777/820\approx 94.756\%$ and the men averaged $613/820\approx 74.756\%$.  Both satisfy the conditions of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

$W$, average score from the women.

$M$, average score of the men.

$x$, total number of female students.

$x+80$, total number of male students

$$
\frac{M(x+80)+W(x)}{x+(x+80)}=.75
$$

$$
W=.2+M
$$

$$
(W-.2)(x+80)+xW=.75(2x+80)
$$

$$
xW+80W-.2x-16+xW=1.5x+60
$$

$$
W(2x+80)=1.7x+76
$$

$$
W=\frac{1.7x+76}{2x+80}
$$

You need to know how many female students there are in this class to answer this question.